# How to use skills input form dynamically in education form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

How to use skills in text area form dynamically in education form?

I want that when user enters his/her skills in text area then when they press tab button, the skill is automatically colored and focus on next skill. Is there any bootstrap or jQuery plugin or not?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <textarea rows="3" cols="70" class="form-control" id="skills" name="skills" placeholder="Professional Skills" ></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are talking about separate textareas for each skill, the following should work. All the text in a single textarea must be the same color. You will need some more logic if you want to switch back to black if the user removes the text, or if they shift-tab, etc.

```js
$(".skill-area").on("blur", function(event) {
  var $area = $("#" + event.target.id);
  if (event.target.value.length > 0 && !$area.hasClass("entered")) {
    $area.addClass("entered");
  }
});
```

```css
.entered {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="form-group">
      <textarea rows="3" cols="70" class="form-control skill-area" id="skill1" name="skill1" placeholder="Professional Skills" ></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <textarea rows="3" cols="70" class="form-control skill-area" id="skill2" name="skill2" placeholder="Professional Skills" ></textarea>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```